# Facebook FQL : Need large src url from stream table (attachment - media)

Tags: facebook, image, stream, attachment

By FQL stream table return newsfeed by fql with attachment attribute. attachment contain media information and in media there is an src attribute which contain photo url. I need to change those photo url as big image url..

[{ attachment:{ media:[{ src:...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the media src is an image that is uploaded on facebook then you can change the filename of the src ending with  '_s.jpg' to '_n.jpg' and it will display the original image that was uploaded to facebook, i.e. the bigger image.

You can identify these images that have been uploaded to facebook by the start of the url in the src -  `https://fbcdn`. The external images cannot be changed to get bigger images. These can be identified by the start of the url - `https://fbexternal`

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: thanx neil, but i don't want to do some kind of hack in facebook, facebook maight be chage standards any time i.e "_s.jpg" etc..right
Thanx again for your ans :)

Comment: @Ajit Another alternative would be to return the "photo" attribute within media. Within the photo array there is an fbid. This is the fbid of the photo. You could then do a second request (https://graph.facebook.com/[fbid]) to return all the properties of this photo. This new object returned has an attribute "source" that contains the "_n". Hope this makes sense.

Comment: yes that's defiantly helpful to me,..thanx neil, i already do that but  i think if we can apply join in FQL then it's possible in single API call... :)

Comment: @Ajit if you use an fql multiquery you can do this in one call. More information on this can be found on the [facebook developers blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/257/)

Comment: i think multiquery is only use when we have only one output for subquery, but in our case we want multiple photos base on fbid so it's quite difficult :) thanks again..